# Passing argument to Container View's view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have view A with view controller A and view B with view controller B.

View A has a `Container View` which I've held down control + dragged to view B to make an association. At this point running the app shows view B inside view A's `Container View`

From view controller B I can programmatically change properties, but I'd like to change properties once it's loaded (or perhaps control the initialization of view B showing up in the Container View).

What I have is a wizard step (view B) and I want to highlight different icons based on the view that is consuming it, but I'm not sure how to call into the view controller B from view controller A (or if that's even the approach I want to take).

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about a "container view" that you dragged out of the object library? There is no such thing as a UIContainer.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, sorry, container view

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepareForSegue to get a reference to the controller in the container view from the main controller (controller A in your case). That controller will be the segue's destinationViewController, and prepareForSegue will be called as soon as the two controllers are instantiated (which happens one right after the other).

Answer (score 1):

In your storyboard set an Identifier for the segue between A & B and then in Controller A add this code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"]) {
        ViewControllerB *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.property = value; // You can pass any value from A to B here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is super slick and works great. Thanks for the code example.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a single view controller that has the desired number of UIViews you want to have. This way you can control all the views from a single controller without needing to switch controllers. You can hide and show the views (and highlight the icons) according to your scenarios.